# Extract data based on certain pattern in one column

Tags: text-processing, awk, bioinformatics

I have a dataset like this:

```
AAACCTGCAAGCGAGT-1,ENSG00000000419,DPM1,2
AAACCTGCAAGCGAGT-1,ENSG00000001497,LAS1L,1
AAACCTGCAAGCGAGT-1,ENSG00000002330,BAD,1
AAACCTGCAAGCGAGT-1,ENSG00000002549,MT-CO3,2
AAACCTGCAAGCGAGT-1,ENSG00000002586,CD99,5
AAACCTGCAAGCGAGT-1,ENSG00000002834,LASP1,1
AAACCTGCAAGCGAGT-1,ENSG00000003056,M6PR,1
AAACCTGCAAGCGAGT-1,ENSG00000003402,MT-CYB,2
AAACCTGCAAGCGAGT-1,ENSG00000004059,ARF5,2
AAACCTGCAAGCGAGT-1,ENSG00000004455,AK2,1
AAACCTGCAAGCGAGT-1,ENSG00000004468,CD38,8
AAACCTGCAAGCGAGT-1,ENSG00000004779,NDUFAB1,3
AAACCTGCAAGCGAGT-1,ENSG00000004975,DVL2,1
AAACCTGCAAGCGAGT-1,ENSG00000005022,SLC25A5,6
```

I want to get the data that third columns contains mitocondrial genes which is have pattern "MT-", for example, the dataset above, I would like to extract:

```
AAACCTGCAAGCGAGT-1,ENSG00000002549,MT-CO3,2
AAACCTGCAAGCGAGT-1,ENSG00000003402,MT-CYB,2
```

I use this command:

```
awk '$3 ~/^MT-/ {print $1, $2, $3, $4} final_matrix.csv
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: The default field separator in `awk` is a space.  Your data uses a comma as the field separator.  Refer to the `awk` man page, particularly the `-F` option.

Comment: If any of the answers solves your issue, please consider ["accepting" the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). This is the best way to show gratitude on this site.  Accepting an answer not only marks the question as resolved, but also signals to _future readers_ that the accepted answer actually solved the issue.  More information about this is available here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: My previous comment applies to you other questions as well, none of which have accepted answers.  If an answer is confusing or does not work, you should comment on it to say so to give the answerer a chance to clarify or correct it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Awk expects whitespace separated fields by default - if your file is comma-separated, you will need to set the field separator accordingly, either using the `-F` command line option or by setting the internal `FS` awk variable.

If you want the output to be comma separated as well, you need to set `OFS`.

Ex.

```
$ awk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS=FS} $3 ~ /^MT-/ {print $1, $2, $3, $4}' final_matrix.csv
AAACCTGCAAGCGAGT-1,ENSG00000002549,MT-CO3,2
AAACCTGCAAGCGAGT-1,ENSG00000003402,MT-CYB,2
```

Comment: It works now, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

All answers are correct, in addition you can print the whole line.

And there is no need to get into field parsing.

```
awk  '/,MT-/{print}' final_matrix.csv
```

Comment: No need for the `{print}` either as that's awks default action given a true condition.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is right, but you forgot to tell `awk` how to delimit the column entries such that `$1` would be distinguished from `$2` till the rest of the columns. Right now it is just looking for a single white-space to delimit your text on, but ended up finding the whole line on `$1` and didn't find `$3` at all. So `$3 ~ ..` would just be a false condition, resulting in *none* of the lines getting printed.

```
awk -v FS=, -v OFS=, '$3 ~/^MT-/ {print $1, $2, $3, $4}' final_matrix.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your posted example you could just do:

```
grep ',MT-/' final_matrix.csv
```

but if you wanted to use awk and focus on the 3rd field then it'd just be:

```
awk -F, '$3 ~ /^MT-/' final_matrix.csv
```

or:

```
awk -F, 'index($3,"MT-")==1' final_matrix.csv
```